# How do I change a setting in a postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to add a default to a field in a table that has already been created. Is it possible to make this change without having to reinitialize the database entirely? I'm trying to avoid having to recreate all my test data.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE SET DEFAULT` -- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE X (A INT, B INT, C TEXT);
```

And you want to set the default for B to be 5. You can say:

```
ALTER TABLE X ALTER COLUMN B SET DEFAULT 5;
```